# Can't login to Django admin panel after successfully creating superuser using Django custom user model

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, django-admin

After I create superuser in command line, it says the superuser is created successfully, but when I try to log in it says "Please enter the correct email address and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive." I tried to delete all migrations and database and try again but it did not help.

**Here is my model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy
# Create your models here.

class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, Email, Password = None, **other_fields):
        
        if not Email:
            raise ValueError(gettext_lazy('You must provide email address'))

        email = self.normalize_email(Email)
        user = self.model(Email=email , **other_fields)
        user.set_password(Password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
       
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, Email, Password = None, **other_fields):
        
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        return self.create_user(Email=Email, Password = Password, **other_fields)

class Customer(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    Email = models.EmailField(gettext_lazy('email address'), max_length=256, unique=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)
    Surname = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)
    Birthday = models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True,blank=True)
    PhoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    RegistrationDate  = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = UserAccountManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'Email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name + " " + self.Surname

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj = None):
        return self.is_superuser
```

**Here is my admin.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from .models import *
# Register your models here.

class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('Email', 'Name', 'Surname')
    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('Email', 'Name','Surname','Birthday','PhoneNumber','Address', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser')
    def clean_password(self):

        return self.initial["password"]

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm


    list_display = ('Email', 'Name', 'Surname')
    list_filter = ('is_superuser','Email', 'Name', 'Birthday')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('Email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('Birthday','Name','Surname')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_superuser',)}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = ()
    search_fields = ('Email',)
    ordering = ('Email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

      
admin.site.register(Customer,UserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In:

```
 def create_user(self, Email, Password = None, **other_fields):
```

Remove = None, leaving Password only.

And add password=password as below:

```
user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(
email), username=username, password=password)

  user = self.create_user(email=self.normalize_email(
email), username=username, password=password)
```

Hope it fixes it. If you still cannot log in, run python manage.py createsuperuser and create a new superuser and try to log in with that one.